# How to rename part of a url with .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I currently have very little Apache experience, and am having difficulties with my .htaccess file. My question is this: how can I rename these files, listed below, properly? I believe my syntax is accurate, according to [http://www.htaccesscheck.com](http://www.htaccesscheck.com/), but when accessing these pages, either A: the page won't load due to a redirect loop, or B: the page won't load, but will redirect to the wrong page. Here is my current .htaccess file for this directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /photos/

RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are the `.htaccess` and `*.php` files in a subdirectory named `/photos`?

Comment: Then there should be no endless loop. The rules look correct, apart from `catpost.php` swallowing every request. Can you specify what requests are wrong and where you get an endless loop?

Comment: When I try to access index.php in this directory, the endless loop error appears for some reason, and when I try to view a particular post, ex viewpost.php?id=7, which would be renamed to it's post slug, I am redirected to index.php @OlafDietsche

Comment: I tested your rules in my environment and they won't do what you want, but there is no endless loop. This loop could only happen, if the .htaccess file is in the document root directory.

Comment: Very strange. @OlafDietsche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /photos/

RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{4})$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This rules will check, if:

- request like yourdomain/11-1111, then return archives.php
- request like yourdomain/111, then return catpost.php (you can type
  any number)
- else will return viewpost

You have some errors in your current .htaccess, because your second rule get result of first rule.

By the way, you can use http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to check step by step what is posted to your rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're an animal!

Comment: It is, don't worry Lol

Answer (score 0):

be sure to write a valid pattern

try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /photos/

RewriteRule ^(.*?)-(.*?)$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: How is this different from the original rules?

Comment: This is the same syntax as my current .htaccess